# Cygwin calling convention

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, dll, cygwin

I have compiled a c++ dll using cygwin gcc,  now I am trying to load it from native windows compiler, and call functions, they have different function name mangling, my compiled dll have classes and is 64bit.
I Have .def file generated by dlltool, I have tried to make it lib by visual studio command prompt, but as I understood this 2  def files have different syntax, haven't they ? can I edit it to bring visual studio understandable def file ?

Is it possible to specify calling convention in cygwin gcc for compiling dll ? ,  or 
is it possible to specify calling convention in visual studio for loaded dll without changing header file of dll ?

Thanks

Comment: The name mangling is compiler specific and not part of the calling convention. They are two different things.

Comment: but as I understand name mangling, is dependent to calling convention, for example stdcall has its specific mangling, cdecl its specific. Am I correct ? or I don't understand well enough ?

Comment: Calling conventions defines how the parameters of a method are passed and who is responsible for cleaning up the stack (if appropriate). As far as I know, the name mangling only determines how the name of a method is generated to support overloading. Of course this also depends on the parameters of a method, but are two totally different concepts which happen to share the same input.

Comment: You can't link C++ libaries compiled with GCC with executables compiled with with MSVC++, or vice versa. They have different name-mangling protocols and in general different ABIs. They're incompatible.

Comment: Visual studio  have tool to convert .def extension file  to lib, Can I use this to make name mangling understandable ?